# Getting a black image generated from a blob URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a library [react-avatar-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-avatar-editor) for creating profile picture of the user. Below is the code which I am using the send the cropped image to the server

```
const canvasScaled = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas(); //a canvas object
canvasScaled.toBlob((blob) => {
  this.setState({
      preview: blob
    },
    () => {
      let data = new FormData();
      const file = new File([blob], "my-image", {
        type: "image/png"
      });
      data.append("file", file);
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: "/media",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then().catch()
    }
  );
})
```

But the image generated at the server is a black image. Tested with many files but result is same - a black image.

My backend service is written in JAVA so I tested if the backend service handling the image correctly or not, I wrote a simple file selected

```
<input type="file" accept={"image/png"} onChange={onSelect}/>

<button onClick={() => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", this.state.file);
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            url: "/media",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then().catch()
}}>Send<button>
```

And yes, the service side code is working fine with above `POST` request. Which means, I have definitely something wrong written at the react-avatar-editor handling code.

Is it the `blob` causing the issue? How the image is sent in the case of a file-selector? Base64 or blob?

Update: I noticed a strange behavior with an image. If I upload this file
[image]
This gets converted to 
[image: Not complete black]
which is not a complete black image. Something fishy is going on with colors.

To check if the library itself is creating the black image, I check it using `canvasScaled.toDataURL("image/png")` and used this into an image, and yes there is no issue with the created canvas, image is getting rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Try `data.append("file", blob);` without calling `new File`. According to MDN,

> A File object is a specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can. In particular, FileReader, URL.createObjectURL(), createImageBitmap(), and XMLHttpRequest.send() accept both Blobs and Files.

Comment: Initially, I was doing that only, but it gives the same result. I used `File` to mimic the normal file selector.

Answer (score 1):

add this in second line after defining **canvasScaled**

```
var ctx = canvasScaled.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Now the image is completely white :D

Comment: And shouldn't `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` be `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasScaled.width, canvasScaled.height);` ?

Comment: add this also
**ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'**

Comment: No luck, still a white image.